# inline-block при 100%-ой ширине элемента

Tags: html, css

Верстая макет натолкнулся на проблему - на странице присутствует слайдер. По задумке дизайнера, слайдер должен всегда занимать 100% от ширины монитора и при клике по кнопкам смещаться вправо/влево на ширину 1-го слайда. Слайдер должен также масштабироваться при изменении ширины монитора, то-есть не просто по ширине, а и по высоте (имеется фоновая картинка, которая должна соблюдать пропорции). Вопрос - возможно ли в принципе реализовать такое? Дело в том, что блоки не встают в одну линию не смотря на указание свойства элементов display:inline-block и overflow: hidden родительского элемента. Возможно это как раз из-за 100% ширины элементов?

Comment: Те свойства,что Вы перечислили,не гарантия блоков в одну линию

Comment: А что еще я упустил?

Comment: Если между блоками с `display:inline-block` есть пробелы/переводы строк, то уберите их на всякий случай.

Comment: Нет, пробелов нет. Мне бы просто узнать, можно ли выстроить в ряд несколько блоков, у каждого из которых ширина указана в 100% от родительского элемента?

Comment: Почему нет,если это flex контейнер

Comment: то-есть только через display:flex?

Comment: Ну я сразу вспомнил про flex,у Вас что IE?

Comment: Да нет, просто раньше приходилось делать слайдеры только с блоками фиксированной ширины. Делал их без флексов.

Comment: @КонстантинКучер, Вы пишете свой слайдер? Предполагаю, что задав для контейнера `display: flex`, все пункты слайдера сожмутся до тех размеров, что необходимы для их "вписания" в рамки контейнера. Если только у них не задана `min-width`.

Comment: Игорь, да, именно это и произошло, когда я попытался такое провернуть, так что это тоже не вариант...

Comment: @КонстантинКучер, если пункты слайдера имеют стопроцентную ширину и не обёрнуты в контейнер, где ширина рассчитана исходя из кол-ва отображаемых эл-тов, понятное дело, эти пункты не будут располагаться на одной строке)
Я бы посоветовал вам не выдумывать велосипед, и смотреть в сторону существующих решений. Owl-carousel2, например.

Comment: Спасибо, Игорь! Вот это я и хотел услышать!